# What's the difference between Incremental development and Staged delivery?

Tags: methodology

I am doing reading on development methodology for my university course but both of these sound fairly similar.

> "Staged Lifecycle is an Application Development methodology in which certain intermediate work products (incremental deliveries) will be delivered to the client before final delivery of the entire application"
>
> "The incremental build model is a method of software development where the product is designed, implemented and tested incrementally (a little more is added each time) until the product is finished."

Can someone please explain to me the key differences between them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation: The firs: every time a part of the product is finished it is send to the client. Eventually the client will have all the part and have the final product. The second: the product cannot be send to the client in between because it will not work. The product will be tested every time a part (depended on the previous) is finished until they reach the end result.